# Laravel Artisan Call Wait Time

Tags: laravel, timeout, laravel-artisan

I have laravel using crud generator package, that run with controller with this command

```
Artisan::call("crud:generate", [
        "name" => ucwords(str_singular($request->input('table'))),
        "--fields" => $fields
]);
```

after the controller run, it's show error because the route is not exist. One thing that i know is the crud generator code is fine, but the artisan proccess is not done yet, so it's show error.

After waiting a few of second, and i pres F5 for refreshing page, it's not showing error anymore.

How to make my controller redirect after the artisan call done?